# Wrong result for the Inverse Matrix

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl, matrix-inverse

I want to compute the inverse of a complex matrix through Fortran code and the size of the matrix 52 by 52. I use ZGETRF and ZGETRI functions in MKL library to run a test. If the size of the complex matrix is 2 by 2, these two functions works well because the multiplication of original and inverse matrix is identity matrix; however, I find that if the size of the complex matrices is 3 by 3, the results are wrong because the multiplication of the original and inverse matrices is not identity matrix anymore.

I paste my test code here so that you could refer to it.

I run the test program with a shell script on the cluster and the script is also pasted here.

```
PROGRAM TE
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i, j, dime
DOUBLE COMPLEX, ALLOCATABLE :: a(:,:)
DOUBLE COMPLEX, ALLOCATABLE :: b(:,:)
DOUBLE COMPLEX, ALLOCATABLE :: c(:,:)

!Variables used in LU decomposition subroutine (ZGETRF)
INTEGER                       :: nu_r                 !Number of row in target matrix
INTEGER                       :: nu_c                 !Number of column in target matrix
INTEGER                       :: lu_lda               !Leading dimension of target matrix
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE          :: lu_ipiv(:)           !Array with dimension of .GE. MIN(nu_r,nu_c)
INTEGER                       :: lu_info              !Judgement (0-successful;<0-error and infor = number, then
                                                      !'1-number'th argument has illegal value;>0 and info = 
                                                      !number - LU matrix(number,number) is zero)
!

!Variables used in inverse subroutine (ZGETRI)
INTEGER                       :: nu_o                 !Order of LU matrix
DOUBLE COMPLEX, ALLOCATABLE   :: in_work(:)           !Workspace array with dimension of .GE. MAX(1,in_lwork)
INTEGER                       :: in_lda               !Leading dimension of LU decomposed matrix .GE. MAX(1,nu_o)
INTEGER                       :: in_lwork             !Size of in_work array with value .GE. nu_o
INTEGER                       :: in_info              !Judgement (0-successful;<0-error and infor = number, then
                                                      !'1-number'th argument has illegal value;>0 and info =
                                                      !number; then, LU matrix(number,number) is zero and inversion
                                                      !cannot be accomplished)

dime = 3
ALLOCATE (a(dime,dime))
ALLOCATE (b(dime,dime))
ALLOCATE (c(dime,dime))

DO i = 1, dime, 1
   DO j = 1, dime, 1
      a(i,j) = CMPLX(DBLE(i), DBLE(j))
   END DO
END DO

b = a

OPEN (UNIT=3, FILE='te_in.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')

WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT='(A1)') 'a'
DO i = 1, dime, 1
   DO j = 1, dime, 1
      WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) a(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*)

!Initialising parameters for LU decomposition subroutine (ZGETRF)
nu_r = dime
nu_c = dime
lu_lda = dime
ALLOCATE (lu_ipiv(dime))
lu_ipiv = 0
!

!Initialising parameters for inverse subroutine (ZGETRI)
nu_o = dime
in_lwork = dime
ALLOCATE (in_work(in_lwork))
in_work = (0.0d0, 0.0d0)
in_lda = dime
!

CALL ZGETRF(nu_r,nu_c,b,lu_lda,lu_ipiv,lu_info)
CALL ZGETRI(nu_o,b,in_lda,lu_ipiv,in_work,in_lwork,in_info)

WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT='(A1)') 'b'
DO i = 1, dime, 1
   DO j = 1, dime, 1
      WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) b(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*)

c = MATMUL(a,b)

WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT='(A1)') 'c'
DO i = 1, dime, 1
   DO j = 1, dime, 1
      WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) c(i,j)
   END DO
END DO
WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*)

DEALLOCATE (lu_ipiv)
DEALLOCATE (a)
DEALLOCATE (b)
DEALLOCATE (c)

CLOSE (UNIT=3)
STOP
END PROGRAM TE
```

Below, it is the content of the output file 2 by 2 complex matrix case and it is correct.

```
a
(1.00000000000000,1.00000000000000)
(1.00000000000000,2.00000000000000)
(2.00000000000000,1.00000000000000)
(2.00000000000000,2.00000000000000)

b
(-2.00000000000000,2.00000000000000)
(2.00000000000000,-1.00000000000000)
(1.00000000000000,-2.00000000000000)
(-1.00000000000000,1.00000000000000)

c
(1.00000000000000,-2.220446049250313E-016)
(0.000000000000000E+000,2.220446049250313E-016)
(0.000000000000000E+000,4.440892098500626E-016)
(1.00000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
```

However, the program does not generate correct output content for 3 by 3 complex matrix, which is shown below.

```
a
(1.00000000000000,1.00000000000000)
(1.00000000000000,2.00000000000000)
(1.00000000000000,3.00000000000000)
(2.00000000000000,1.00000000000000)
(2.00000000000000,2.00000000000000)
(2.00000000000000,3.00000000000000)
(3.00000000000000,1.00000000000000)
(3.00000000000000,2.00000000000000)
(3.00000000000000,3.00000000000000)

b
(723205779577744.,262983919846453.)
(-1.446411559155488E+015,-525967839692903.)
(723205779577744.,262983919846451.)
(-1.446411559155489E+015,-525967839692904.)
(2.892823118310976E+015,1.051935679385808E+015)
(-1.446411559155487E+015,-525967839692903.)
(723205779577745.,262983919846452.)
(-1.446411559155488E+015,-525967839692905.)
(723205779577743.,262983919846452.)

c
(0.437500000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(1.25000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(-0.250000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.125000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.500000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.750000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(-0.500000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
(0.000000000000000E+000,-1.00000000000000)
(1.50000000000000,0.500000000000000)
```

I also test my code with the other complex matrices with higher order and the results are all wrong. I paste the shell script below that I use to submit my job to run this test program.

```
#!/bin/bash
module switch PrgEnv-cray PrgEnv-intel
#module load intel
#----------------------------------------------------------#
ifort -O3 te.f90 \
  -Wl,--start-group${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a \
                   ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a \
                   ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a \
  -Wl,--end-group-lpthread -lm –ldl
```

Would anyone please tell what is wrong with my code? Is there something wrong with ZGETRF and ZGETRI functions? Would anyone please give me some suggestions on how to sort it out?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 3):

*(illustration using Mathematica)*

The problem is not related to MKL. Your matrices are singular for `dime>2`. MKL is not supposed to give a correct matrix inverse for a matrix that has no inverse.

```
In[1]:= mat[n_]:=Table[i+I j,{i,1,n},{j,1,n}]
In[2]:= Table[Det[mat[n]],{n,1,20}]
Out[2]= {1+I,-I,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Actually, it's not difficult to see they have rank 2 for `dime>1`.

```
In[3]:= col[n_]:=Table[i+I j,{i,1,n},{j,1,2}]
In[4]:= row[n_]:={Table[2-j,{j,1,n}],Table[j-1,{j,1,n}]}
In[5]:= Table[Norm[mat[n]-col[n].row[n]],{n,2,20}]
Out[5]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

That is, a possible [rank factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) for your matrix is C*R with:

```
C=[1+I 1+2I]
  [2+I 2+2I]
  [...  ...]
  [n+I n+2I]

R=[1 0 -1 ... 2-n]
  [0 1  2 ... n-1]
```

Comment: @kieran : As addition see the `info` parameter of `zgetri` / `zgetrf` about the possible return values (as you already mentioned in the declaration of the info values).

Comment: @albert Actually info=0 for both call. The [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d01/group__complex16_g_ecomputational_gab490cfc4b92edec5345479f19a9a72ca.html) says that *INFO > 0:  if INFO = i, U(i,i) is exactly zero; the matrix is singular and its inverse could not be computed.* But often, due to numerical error, U(i,i) is not exactly zero, it's just a very small value, hence the very large values in the output.

Comment: So actually the problem is because of the the fact that the matrix is logically / by a human seen as singular but due to numerical resolution of a computer (there are some nice articles about this, especially: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, by David Goldberg) it is not detected as such by MKL.

Comment: @albert @ Jean-Claude Arbaut Dear Albert and Jean, Thank you very much for the valuable suggestions. If I want ZGETRF or ZGETRI functions to return the error information (info=i), when dealing with a singular matrix, I need to make the cluster recognize the small value as exactly zero, through changing the resolution. Is my understanding correct? If so, is there any way to modify this numerical resolution setting on cluster; for example, through modifying the compilation file? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kieran If you reduce the precision, you will still have numerical errors. Since the LU code doesn't detect this, it won't work. You may check the determinant afterwards (or preferably the log of the determinant), or the condition number: use the SVD and check the ratio between largest to smallest singular value. And bear in mind that with numerical software you can't really check whether a matrix is singular, you can only check if it is *numerically* singular (that is, close to singular).

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Thank you for the suggestions. I will double check it. On the other hand, it is impossible compute the inverse of the complex matrix, if the determinant of it is very small. Is it correct? Thank you again.

Comment: @Kieran Mathematically, you can invert a matrix as long as its determinant is nonzero. Numerically, however, you will have in general a huge precision loss. But note that in your case the matrix is singular (mathematically), so it makes no sense to count on the numerical errors to get an inverse: you will get "something" because LAPACK can't guess the matrix really is singular, but a "something" that has no mathematical ground. It's you job to check the input matrix is invertible and to use the library wisely. You can't invert this matrix, don't try.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut, Thank you very much for the answer and suggestions. Now, I understand.

Comment: @Kieran By the way, you can get an estimate of the condition number after zgetrf, using [zgecon](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d01/group__complex16_g_ecomputational_gabe73145daeba3ec10e961054b75a07ce.html).

Answer (score 0):

could you check the case with the latest MKL 2019 version? MKL has some problems with getri into version 2018 as I remember exactly.

Comment: Dear Gennady, Thank you very much for the suggestions. I will check it. On the other hand, would you please recommend me some other solution? Is there any other stable FORTRAN function or current stable FORTRAN code, computing the inverse of the complex matrix?

Comment: @Kieran the xGETRF and xGETRI subroutines are part of LAPACK. There are many implementations of LAPACK  and MKL contains one of them .But there are other ones, including the reference one http://www.netlib.org/lapack/ that is present in most Linux distributions and linked with `-llapack` and `-lblas`. However, see the other answer.

Comment: @Vladimir F Thank you very much for the suggestions. I will search for more solutions.